# Use WIX to create a database with a script instead of a SQLDatabase element

Tags: wix

I want to use WIX to create a database during my installation. I know I can do this using a SqlDatabase element like this:

```
<sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlDatabase' Database='MyDB'  Server='localhost'  Instance='MyInst'
                  CreateOnInstall='yes' DropOnUninstall='yes' ContinueOnError='yes'>
                <sql:SqlScript Id='CreateTables' BinaryKey='CreateTables' ExecuteOnInstall='yes'/>
              </sql:SqlDatabase>
```

The problem is that I want to create the database in the script file and not in the SqlDatabase element. Is there a way to do this?

If I set CreateOnInstall to 'no', the script wont' run.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the SqlDatabase element to connect to the master database (or any other database you know exists), then the SqlScript can do all the work you want. You'll may need to update your SqlScript such that it targets the correct database.

```
<sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlDatabase' Database='master'  Server='localhost'  Instance='MyInst'>
   <sql:SqlScript Id='CreateTables' BinaryKey='CreateTables' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
</sql:SqlDatabase>
```

Comment: With your snippet, you won't be able to compile the MSI package and you'll get the following error: The sql:SqlDatabase element must have one of the following attributes specified: CreateOnInstall, CreateOnUninstall, DropOnInstall or DropOnUninstall.

Comment: Your code is not working, in my case (VS 2019, WiX Extension) it will produce the error which Dan already described.